# ON DUPLICATE KEY doesn't work with my INSERT INTO script

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054, mysql-error-1052

I have two tables. One is `permission_index` and the other is `permission_index_bkp`.

My script is supposed to transfer some rows and data from `permission_index` to `permission_index_bkp`. However, I don't want to create new rows if the data in all 4 columns is the same.

This is what I am trying to use:

```
INSERT INTO permission_index_bkp
  (b_app, b_perm_type, b_perm_type_id, b_perm_3)
  SELECT app, perm_type, perm_type_id, perm_3
    FROM permission_index
   WHERE app = 'module'
     AND perm_type = '1'
     AND perm_type_id = '2'
     AND perm_3 IS NOT NULL 
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE app = app,
                              perm_type = perm_type, 
                              perm_type_id = perm_type_id,
                              perm_3 = perm_3;
```

I've been getting errors like:

**1052: Column 'app' in field list is ambiguous** (I think I fixed this by changing columns' name in permission_index_bkp).

or

**1054: Unknown column 'app' in 'field list'**

Could you guys tell me how to fix my query?

Thanks!!

**EDIT 1:**

This has made the errors disappear, however, rows keep being added in `permission_index_bkp`, even though they have the same values:

```
INSERT INTO permission_index_bkp
  (b_app, b_perm_type, b_perm_type_id, b_perm_3)
  SELECT app, perm_type, perm_type_id, perm_3
    FROM permission_index AS pi
   WHERE app = 'module'
     AND perm_type = '1'
     AND perm_type_id = '2'
     AND perm_3 IS NOT NULL 
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b_app = b_app,
                              b_perm_type = b_perm_type, 
                              b_perm_type_id = b_perm_type_id,
                              b_perm_3 = b_perm_3;
```

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Sorry, I'm not sure I get that. Would you mind rephrasing it please, or posting a complete example? Thank you!! EDIT: I think I get it now. I'll give it a try!

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan same 1052 error, unfortunately.

Comment: `app = app` should be `app = VALUES(app)` and the same for the rest of the assignments.

Comment: @Barmar I have just edited the main post. Do you think changing it to VALUES(b_app) should solve it, then? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `VALUES()` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause to specify that you want to update a column to the value that would have been inserted.

And you need to be assigning to the column names in the destination table, not the names in the table you're selecting from, so they should all be `b_XXX`.

```
INSERT INTO permission_index_bkp
  (b_app, b_perm_type, b_perm_type_id, b_perm_3)
  SELECT app, perm_type, perm_type_id, perm_3
    FROM permission_index
   WHERE app = 'module'
     AND perm_type = '1'
     AND perm_type_id = '2'
     AND perm_3 IS NOT NULL 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    b_app = VALUES(b_app),
    b_perm_type = VALUES(b_perm_type), 
    b_perm_type_id = VALUES(b_perm_type_id),
    b_perm_3 = VALUES(b_perm_3);
```

Also, you don't need to include the unique key column(s) in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause.

Comment: Hi! Using that still gives me a 1054 error. Changing app to b_app (...) made it go away. However, I still see duplicate rows being added to `permission_index_bkp`.

Comment: What is the unique key of `permission_index_bkp`?

Comment: It has to be one of the columns you're inserting into. Otherwise, how do you expect it to know that it's a duplicate?

Comment: Sorry. I just got started with MySQL. Do these help you? 1. Columns: https://i.imgur.com/ODMzZzm.png 2. DDL: https://pastebin.com/jENYPR5A

Comment: You need to make `perm_index` a `UNIQUE KEY`.

Comment: I ended up making all relevant columns UNIQUE KEYS. That seems to have solved it. I also changed `b_app = VALUES(app)` (...) in your code to `b_app = VALUES(b_app)`. Do these changes look okay to you? Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help, Barmar!! The only thing I still don't understand is the actual difference between `b_app=b_app` and `b_app = VALUES(b_app)`.

Comment: `b_app` is the value of the column that's already in the table. `VALUES(b_app)` is the value you're trying to insert.

Answer (score 2):

Though I never used this syntax but after doing some search in google I found that you need to declare an unique key on all four columns of your `permission_index` table to remove duplicate entries.

Please check below example:

```
 create table test (a int, b int);
 insert into test values(1,1);
 insert into test values(1,2);

 create table test2 (a int, b int,
 UNIQUE KEY uktest2 (a,b));

 INSERT INTO test2
   (a,b)
   SELECT a,b
     FROM test b
    WHERE a=1
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = b.a,
                               b=b.b;


 select * from test;
 select * from test2;
```

Output:

table test:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

table test2:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

```
 insert into test values(1,3);
 insert into test values(1,1);


 INSERT INTO test2
   (a,b)
   SELECT a,b
     FROM test b
    WHERE a=1
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = b.a,
                               b=b.b;


 select * from test;
 select * from test2;
```

Output:

table test:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 |

table test2:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=aca0867a598c8fb3df27a89ac1330231)*

Comment: I never used this syntax but  is `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE app = app` ok without alias?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying. I have just edited the main post with a new code. It made the errors disappear, but identical rows keep being created in `permission_index_bkp`.

Comment: Yes, it's okay without an alias.

Comment: That seems to have solved it!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Hilas you are most welcome. Best wishes.